# After disabling autosave function in wordpress Confirm Navigation window stops appearing when leaving unsaved page in admin

Tags: javascript, wordpress, alert, autosave

I managed to disable autosaving drafts in **Wordpress 4.3** by calling `wp_dequeue_script('autosave')`.

But the window with leave confirmation:

> Do you really want to leave unsaved page...

stops appearing and i want it to stay. I can't figure how this window alert hooks to autosave action in wordpress.

The example of such window can be seen [here](https://demos1.softaculous.com/WordPress/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page).

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `wp_dequeue_script` and put this instead in your *wp_config.php*:

```
define('AUTOSAVE_INTERVAL', 86400);
```

This will tell Wordpress to autosave drafts only after one day. You can change this to whatever value you want.

Comment: this one is not helping, drafts still saving after first edit of title field

Comment: Well, Wordpress is generating the permalink the first time you edit the title. I think you'll have hard time to disable this without hacking into core. Just curious, why do you need to disable this?